# Create react library - assets bundle

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, assets

I have created a react typescript project using "create-react-library".

The project export a component, let's call it "A".

The "A" component render an svg image which is inside the component folder.

But when i compile the library project (using microbundle), there is no assets in dist folder.
And as a result, if i use component "A" in a test example project, i cannot see the svg image.

I have not found any example which handle this scenario.